# Sublime Text: see how many resources each plugin is using

Tags: plugins, cpu-load, sublime-text, top

How can I see how many resources each Sublime Text plugin is using?

Answer (score 0):

You can open System Monitor and check a process called `plugin_host`. This is a Sublime Text process containing all the plugin resources of the editor. If you want to see specifically the resource of each plugin, you may want to install this Sublime Text plugin: [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer)

Comment: Please note that package resource viewer doesn't display the system resources in use by each plugin. It allows you to inspect and edit package files.

Comment: Cheers for this. I discovered Sublime Text was using a lot of CPU resources not because of a plugin but because it was trying to index the tmp folder of my project. I fixed the problem by configuring `folder_exclude_patterns`.

Comment: @AshtonWar, how were you able to figure that out?

Comment: @AustinHanson Lucky guess. Googled something like "sublime how to exclude folders from ctrl+p" and found [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html?highlight=folder_exclude_pattern)

Comment: @AshtonWar, I'm glad you had that guess. That was exactly my problem as well. :) Thanks